# Passing data from textbox on the page to textbox on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in my page that contains a textbox and button.
I have a bootstrap popup that contains textbox, captcha and a button.

Question 1. I know how to process the data submitted from the popup. I only need to know how to pass the data entered on the textbox (of the page) to the text box (on popup).

Question 2. After clicking the button on the page and showing the popup, it should clear the textbox (on the page).

Thanks

Comment: Question 3. Where is your code ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue once before.  You can use jquery to grab the value from the text box and place it in the modal(pop ups) text box.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--the JQuery to grab the value and change the textbox-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#page-button').click(function () {
                $('#modal-text').val($('#textbox').val());
                $('#textbox').val("");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <!--textbox on main page-->
        <input id="textbox" type="text" />
        <!--the following has been taken and edited from w3schools from Modals-->
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button id="page-button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- The Modal text box-->
                        <input id="modal-text" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="close-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I need, thanks, but I also want to clear the textbox on the page after the modal popup shows

Comment: I added an extra jquery line that should do that, now.

Answer (score 0):

So process the input form from the page when submitted. You can call a javascript function when submitting the form. In that function reassign the value of division of popup to the submitted data and clear the data of division of form from the page.

For the syntax and how to process form you can visit these links:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_elements
2. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_input_examples.asp